# Low hashrate with cgminer 3.7.2 kalroth edition @ ubuntu 13.10 x64 @ R9 290 MSI GAMING EDITION @ 16 gb ram @ core i7 860

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, ubuntu, scrypt

I'm trying with (below my sh file):

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
cd /home/x/cgminer-3.7.2-kalroth/
find *.bin -delete
sleep 3

cgminer --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://stratum.fast-pool.com:3333 -u user.x -p pass --thread-concurrency 24550 --lookup-gap 2 --auto-gpu --gpu-engine 950 --gpu-memclock 1250 -w 512 -I 20 --gpu-powertune 20 --auto-fan --gpu-fan 40-100 --temp-overheat 90 --temp-target 85 --temp-cutoff 95 -g 1
```

This gives me average ~660 kh :(

I was trying also with config from GUI miner for windows called "R9 290 high":

```
cgminer --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://stratum.fast-pool.com:3333 -u user.x -p pass --thread-concurrency 32765 --lookup-gap 2 --auto-gpu --gpu-engine 950 --gpu-memclock 1250 -w 256 -I 20 --gpu-powertune 20 --auto-fan --gpu-fan 40-100 --temp-overheat 80 --temp-target 75 --temp-cutoff 85 -g 1
```

but it gives e something like this:

```
 [2014-02-13 11:00:29] Started cgminer 3.7.2
 [2014-02-13 11:00:29] Started cgminer 3.7.2
 [2014-02-13 11:00:29] Probing for an alive pool
 [2014-02-13 11:00:29] Pool 0 difficulty changed to 128
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Maximum buffer memory device 0 supports says 774897664
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Your scrypt settings come to 2147287040
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Error -61: clCreateBuffer (padbuffer8), decrease TC or increase LG
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Failed to init GPU thread 0, disabling device 0
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Restarting the GPU from the menu will not fix this.
 [2014-02-13 11:00:34] Try restarting cgminer.
```

Above configs works fine (better hashrate) on windows 7 64, but i prefer to use ubuntu beacause windows is unstable.

Anyone can help me?

I have installed latest catalyst, sdk ofcourse.

Comment: Check out [this reddit thread where people post their configs and hash rates](http://www.reddit.com/r/litecoinmining/comments/1s6g4p/if_youre_running_an_r9_gpu_please_leave_your/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have R9 290 you likely need patched Catalyst drivers as well as patch cgminer itself as described [here](http://www.ohmpie.com/mining-on-an-r9-290-in-linux/). If you already done so, then search reddit and experiment with different configurations. You should be getting around 840-870kH/s with your card.